# Using Vagrant unable to create symlink that has backslash in it when updating branch

Tags: git, vagrant

We recently added a symlink in our repository. The symlink corresponds to a filename on a client's system. The filename is equivalent to: `TheCompany File\' image^^new.txt`  (backslash, apostrophe and carets are all present in filename). That filename then becomes a symbolic link on our system to the file we associate it to. This all works fine up in our linux environment.

I have a vagrant box running the same linux down on my windows 10 machine. The vagrant is 100% capable of handling symlinks and does all the time. However, I believe that backslash in the file name is causing an issue. I have tried everything to merge the latest master with my local copy buy I keep getting the following error:

`error: unable to create symlink TheCompany File\' image^^new.txt (Protocol error)`

I have a fair amount of experience with vagrant and linux. I am a novice git user.

How can I fix this issue and update my local repository with the latest copy of our master branch. I DO NOT need that file in my local branch, but I have been unable to exclude it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is mainly a Vagrant issue: if you're trying to use a shared file system (so that the files are actually stored on Windows) you'll have this problem as Windows can't handle the path. Use a simulated disk (so that you can have a local Linux FS) and the problem will vanish. If you really must share, share via Git, not via shared-file-system; but if you *really* must share, you'll have to stop using that file name.

Comment: How do I create a simulated disk using a linux file system on Windows 10? I started to create a simulated disk in Windows 10, but it only gives me two options for file system. exFAT and NTFS.

Comment: I thought you were running a Linux image inside the Vagrant VM...? If not, pay no attention to the earlier comment. If so, Vagrant just needs a big file to write on as if it were a disk drive.

Comment: (see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/disks/configuration for details - took me a while to find this page again)

Comment: I am running a linux image inside Vagrant. However, the repository (website) files live in a windows directory that is mounted when the vagrant file boots up (so it becomes /var/www/website within the linux vm). I assume you need the windows directory to be an ext4 formatted drive?

Comment: Isn't there a way through git that I can tell git I don't want that file to be part of my local master repository (but still leave it untouched in origin/master)?

Comment: Yes, ext4 or any other Linux-only file system format would work well. (Git really doesn't work well on shared mount points; I have run into all kinds of bizarre behavior with Vagrant on macOS here. Most commonly, it mostly works but suddenly goes excruciatingly slowly, as in 10+ seconds to run a simple command.) Meanwhile, on the Git-only side: you *can* use the sparse checkout mode. It's not really intended for this, but it can be hammered into working here. I'm not sure exactly what commands you'll need to run though.